# Code Reviewing a Pull Request With Master Merges

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Our team has adopted the common PR strategy of having each feature branch code reviewed before being merged to the main branch. We also have adopted the strategy of frequently merging in the main branch to avoid huge conflicts once the branch is done.

This has worked well, but we're facing issues with branches that take longer to build. I'm looking at code reviewing a branch that took a couple weeks to build. There are well over 100 commits of over 100 files in the PR. Now, the actual feature is probably only about 15% of those, the rest are just merges with the main branch.

Is there any way I can shrink this down and only focus on the new code in this branch, as opposed to having to sift through 100's of lines of code that's actually already been code reviewed and merged to the main branch?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for this case is to [rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing). You'll often see this asked for in open source repositories where your feature branch may have become out of date with the master branch.

It would mean that you rewind your branch history, set it to the tip of the current branch you rebase onto, then re-apply your unique changes again, so everything is up to date.

**Caveat:** fixing merge conflicts can be confusing for long running branches while rebasing because you need to fix conflicts at various stages through your feature branch's maturity - often you forget what you did!

You can also merge the main branch into your feature branch which will apply the changes *on top* of your changes. I don't like this approach, because it sort of buries your changes under irrelevant code to your feature, but it's easier to fix conflicts this way because your code is in a "finished" state when you do it.

Answer (score 0):

You compare not with featurebranch base, but with mergebase of future merge, which is last master commit which was merged. This way you see only what was done in the feature branch.

You can do it without looking for the commit, by calling `git diff master...feature` (note 3 dots there)

see [man git-diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)